# Correct Formatting Code Defining

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to add the following code:

```
data: {
    name: info, 
    recptid: '<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>', 
    name: info,
    q:'<?php echo $q; ?>',
    name: info, 
    me: '<?php echo $me; ?>'
},
```

To my existing code below

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit_button").click(function() {
        var textcontent = $("#content").val();
        var dataString = 'content='+ textcontent;

        if (textcontent == '') {
            alert("Enter some text..");
            $("#content").focus();
        } else {
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="load">Loading..</span>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "actions/action_comment.php",    
                // i want to add my code here but i get an error when I do 
                data: dataString,
                cache: true,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#show").after(html);
                    document.getElementById('content').value = '';
                    $("#flash").hide();
                    $("#content").focus();  
                }  
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

How can I add my code with the formatting correctly inserted?

My error is below when I add it code:

[image]

Comment: what does info stands for here?

Comment: The error means you have no variable named `info` that's in scope of where you're attempting to use it. Also the object you're trying to create is invalid as you repeat the `name` property multiple times. Only the value of the last one will be accessible.

Comment: And if `info` is a variable, why `name` is defined 3 times? If it is not a variable, wrap it with quotes...

Comment: Thanks I see my errors now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, JS objects should be defined as `data = {}` not as `data: {}` assuming that `data` is already declared (`var data = {}` otherwise).

Second, the issue that `info` is being interpreted as a variable here, except you don't seem to have an existing `info` variable already. So replacing info with hard-coded information such as "123" or defining `info` before this array should fix your issue, like this:

```
var info = "123"; // or even info = 123;
data= {
    name: info, 
    recptid: '<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>', 
    name: info,
    q:'<?php echo $q; ?>',
    name: info, 
    me: '<?php echo $me; ?>'
};
```

**Edit**: As mentioned in the comments, `name` is defined more than once. Keys/properties have to be unique in JS objects.